# Jquery DataTable deletion applies on the first row only

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a table with a couple of rows

[image]

I want to delete all rows that contain 'Rabat' as a city, but nothing happened. However, when I changed the first row's value it worked. 
So why it works for the first row only ?

Here is my code :

```
$("#btnSave").click(function() { 
       var table = $("#mainTable").DataTable({});
       var nodes = [];

       table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
          if (this.data()[3] == 'Rabat') 
              nodes.push(this.node())
       })
       nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          table.row(node).remove().draw()
       })
});
```

HTML code :

```
<table id="mainTable" class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                                <th>City</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.id</td>
                                    <td>@item.name</td>
                                    <td>@item.country</td>
                                    <td>@item.city</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        }
     </table>
```

Comment: `this.data()[3]` will be the issue.

Comment: But why it works for the first row ?

Comment: When I debug my code I find the first row normal, but the others are undefined

Comment: what are you using for first row? Can you write the code which one is working?

Comment: I have a foreach loop that get the data from the database. I'll edit the post to add another tag for ASP.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accidently create multiple `<tbody>`'s

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>@item.id</td>
      <td>@item.name</td>
      <td>@item.country</td>
      <td>@item.city</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
}
```

should be

```html
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td>@item.id</td>
      <td>@item.name</td>
      <td>@item.country</td>
      <td>@item.city</td>
   </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

DataTables can only handle one `<tbody>` at a time, thats why it only works with the first row.

Besides that you should use `var table = $("#mainTable").DataTable()` when you retrieve the dataTable instance; if you use curly brackets i.e pass an object you accidently reinitalise the table as well.

Comment: Oh my god ! I didn't pay attention to it ! Thank you @davidkonrad